# What is the correct python query to pull phone number type in Twilio Lookup api and why?

Tags: python-3.x, twilio, twilio-api

Based on Twilio Lookup docs https://www.twilio.com/docs/lookup/api?code-sample=code-carrier-lookup-with-e164-formatted-number&code-language=Python&code-sdk-version=6.x
I assume the following:

```
phone_number = client.lookups.phone_numbers('+19234567890').fetch(type=['carrier'])
```

returns:

```
{
  "caller_name": null,
  "carrier": {
    "error_code": null,
    "mobile_country_code": "123",
    "mobile_network_code": "987",
    "name": "verizon",
    "type": "mobile"
  },
  "country_code": "US",
  "national_format": "(923) 456-7890",
  "phone_number": "+19234567890",
  "add_ons": null,
  "url": "https://lookups.twilio.com/v1/PhoneNumbers/+19234567890?Type=carrier"
}
```

Why does

```
print(phone_number['carrier']['type'])
```

return an error TypeError: 'PhoneNumberInstance' object is not subscriptable

But:

```
print(phone_number.carrier['type'])
```

Correctly return "mobile"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The docs show the full JSON response that the API returns. However we built the libraries to return objects that you can call regular methods on. So, the `phone_number` object returned here:

```py
phone_number = client.lookups.phone_numbers('+19234567890').fetch(type=['carrier'])
```

has methods defined, based on our API definitions, for things like `carrier`, `country_code`, and `national_format`.

On the other hand, I don't think we necessarily have a definition for that carrier object, so it is returned as a dictionary. Thus, to look into fields on the carrier you need to use the index (`[]`) operator.

You can check [the definition of the `phone_number` object on GitHub here](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-python/blob/master/twilio/rest/lookups/v1/phone_number.py#L159-L288).

Comment: What you are saying makes sense - now I understand it better. Can you touch on the reasoning behind why `phone_number = client.lookups.phone_numbers('+19234567890').fetch(type=['carrier'])` returns a phone_number object instead of JSON. I assume if this hypothetical JSON was returned then print(phone_number['carrier']['type']) would work?

Comment: Right, the method returns a `PhoneNumberInstance` object instead of a dictionary like you were expecting (which would also work with your call to `phone_number['carrier']['type']`). While this particular object doesn't have any other behaviour, other objects returned from the API may have other methods that do other things rather than just return data. For consistency, all objects returned from API calls are defined objects like this and not dictionaries. One thing you could request in the library would be to implement `__getitem__` for these objects, which would also give you `[]` access.